# 1000:5 current transformer: how to calculate burden resistor?

Tags: arduino

[image]I want to calculate burden resistor for a 1000:5 current transformer. I want to output 5V variation. How do I calculate this burden resistor?

[image]

I using burden resister 220orm .this is out put .input primary 20A and out vmax 43.2 and freq 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CT cannot directly output 5V and maintain rated accuracy.

You need a signal conditioning circuit if you want to get a DC signal suitable to input to an Arduino.

The maximum VA for rated accuracy is 5, so the maximum burden resistor is 0.2\$\Omega\$ (5W) and therefore the output voltage will be 2.8V P-P (at 1kA AC into a 1-turn primary).

Comment: this ct is class A and I won't nectarine 1000A.you have some idea about .please help .

Comment: this ct is class A and I won't nectarine 1000A.you have some idea about .please help

Comment: Nectarine is a fruit. I'm not sure about your question. If you don't need as much as 1000A you can put multiple loops through the primary (4 makes it 250A), but you cannot get more than 2.8V P-P out with full class A accuracy.

Comment: I using 220orm 2 W resister and out put up image..